# При отправке POST запроса при помощи httpurlconnection %20 заменяются на пробелы

Tags: java, android

Для отправки запросов на сервер пользовался `httpurlconnection`. На определённый адрес отправлял пост запросы примерно такого вида `act=GETCOMMENTS&connectid=...` и т.д. И всё вполне работало, приходил ответ от сервера и я его парсил. Но проблема возникла, когда мне посредством этого запроса надо было отправить некий текст. А именно отправка комментария, где в одном из ключей запроса пишется сам комментарий. Примерно так: `&commenttext=test%20test2`. На сервер должно было это прийти именно в таком виде, а сервер сам производит замену `%20` на пробел. Но на сервер приходит именно `test test2` с настоящим пробелом, а не `%20`, а там настоящие пробелы обрезаются.
Вот код метода, который осуществляет все запросы:

```
private String serverRequester2 (String reqParam){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http:/...определённыйСайт.../test.php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        dStream.writeBytes(reqParam);
        Log.d("REQ_PARAM",reqParam);
        dStream.flush();
        dStream.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            Log.d("LINE",line);
            responseOutput.append(line);
        }
        br.close();

        return responseOutput.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

А вот так я его вызываю и передаю ему параметры, которые надо отправить на сервер:

```
return serverRequester2("act=CREATECOMMENT&connectid="+connectid+"&token="+token+"&clientcode=123123123&postid="+postID+"&commenttext=test%20test2");
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему отправляется настоящий пробел, вместо `%20`? Кстати знак `+` он тоже заменяет на пробел. А мне нужно, чтобы серверу пришло именно `test%20test2` или `test+test2`, а не `test test2`.

P.S. сначала была мысль, что всё дело в сервере, но нет, с другого приложения написанного другим человеком на Phonegap запрос приходит именно с URL кодировкой, а не с настоящим пробелом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для отправки текста `test%20test2` нужно передать `test%2520test2`, а для `test+test2` нужно `test%2btest2`.

Детальнее:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding
- http://urlencode.org/
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало!

Answer (score 3):

Все так и должно работать. `%20` это и есть пробел, закодированный для передачи в параметре запроса.
Если хотите, чтобы сервер получил `%20` а не пробел, передавайте `%2520`, т.е. `test%2520test2` в вашем примере.

**ADDON**
Возможно, если убрать это из заголовка

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

сервер перестанет декодировать параметры. Потому что именно он декодирует `%20` в пробел, т.к. вы ему явно говрите, что отправляете закодированные данные.

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало!